# How to prove the Hubble law is the unique expansion law compatible with homogeneity and isotropy?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, cosmology, astronomy, astrophysics

In the book *physical foundations of cosmology*, it saids that Hubble law is unique and a problem seems to be a hint of proving that.

> In order for a general expansion law,**v**=f(**r**,t), to be the same for all observers, the function f must satisfy the relation 
>   $$f(\bf{r_{CA}}−\bf{r_{BA}}, t) = f(\bf{r_{CA}},t)−f(\bf{r_{BA}},t),$$
>   where ABC are three points in space. Show that the only solution of this equation is given by the Hubble law.

With a little help of Taylor approximation, I can convince myself $f$ should be linear and then a linear function without constant. But it seems to me that's not good enough for a proof...So how can one prove it in a more mathy way? 
Thanks !

Comment: I think you mean  the only isotropic solution

Comment: @NaturalPhilosopy I think I used homogeneity to get rid of the constant in the linear form of $f$...